# Android requesting Thumbnails increases heap

Tags: android, heap-memory, thumbnails

My application requests all available thumbnails of the phone via Images.Thumbnails.DATA. It also requests the Images.Media.DATE_ADDED value of each.

If i want to start the app, the screen becomes black (i think it works in the background) and the Log says:
**Grow heap ( frag case ) to 3.373 for 19764-byte allocation**

After a while, Android tells me "Application doesn't respond".

I located the access to the pictures as the reason for this heap grow , how can i solve this problem?

Comment: ur images are too large

Comment: hi my code is too long and complicated to post. As i only display the thumbnails in my activity, i assumed that these couldn't get too large.

Comment: what code u are using to make thuubnails ?